# How's the new dialog with `create new component` can be triggered

Tags: angular, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

This ["What's new"](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/whatsnew/) page mentions the following new capability:

> Angular 2 improvements
>
> Use the New… popup to generate components, directives, services, and
>   other blueprints in projects created with Angular CLI. Completion and
>   resolve for methods in the templates are now more precise because
>   WebStorm understands available type info.

Here is the screenshot showing the functionality:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use the New… popup to generate components, ...

Well... `File | New...` and then choose `Angular CLI` option there.

I suggest to go trough the "WebStorm 2016.3 - New features" video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_THi3bEmp7g -- it's quite short (4 and a half minutes only)

Check this interval: 3:02-3.16 in particular

---

As stated by @lena -- you also need to have `angular-cli.json` in your project for this option to appear.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason the option [is not there for me](https://postimg.org/image/qll7nld4p/). I've got much less entries than the guy on the window. Do you know what might be the cause?

Comment: I guess (as I'm not Angular user myself) you need to *"Install angular-cli globally via npm"* (and IDE should be able to find it) + have AngularJS plugin enabled. Not sure if this project should have been created via `New Project | Angular CLI` option though... But I have tried to do that in new test project and that entry in `New` menu is now there. _(P.S. 199MB in empty project....)_

Comment: this action is only enabled for projects that have `angular-cli.json` file in the project root. Do you have it there?

Comment: @lena, what should be selected in `Angular CLI` input when creating a project? I put a path to `\node_modules\angular-cli` but I still get an error `Please specify angular-cli package`. There is no information on that [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/using-angular-cli.html)

Comment: I'm talking about [this field](https://postimg.org/image/tcuzelawn/). Can the problem be that I'm using `nvm`?

Comment: it should be a path to global cli package, like `C:\Users\Your.Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli`

Comment: @lena, yeah, I'm putting it there, but the error is still there and the `create` button is disabled. Maybe I should create another question?

Comment: @Maximus Have you tried restarting your IDE? I'm on Windows 10 .. and for me the New Project screen picked it up immediately even without restart. I just do not remember exact path .. as I have now deleted that package... but the one lena gave above sounds about right.

Comment: @LazyOne, yeah, I've tried. No luck. Anyways, the feature in question is working if there's `angular-cli.json` in project root. It doesn't matter if I created a project as `Angular-cli` or not. Thanks a lot for your help.